# Why are the two random variables independent in the analysis of Randomized Selection algorithm in CLRS?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms

In section 9.2 of CLRS (*Introduction to Algorithms; page 185 in the 2nd edition and page 215 in the 3rd edition*), a randomized selection algorithm is presented.

For its analysis, $T(n)$ is a random variable denoting the time required on an input array $A[p \cdots r]$ of $n$ elements and $X_k$ is an indicator random variable $X_k = I \{ \text{the subarray } A[p \cdots q] \text{ has exactly } k \text{ elements (due to the pivot)} \}$.

It has been claimed that $X_k$ and $T(\max(k-1, n-k))$ are independent (page 187 in the 2nd edition and page 218 in the 3rd edition). However, I find it quite counter-intuitive to understand. How to verify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two random variables $X_k$ and $T(\max(k-1, n-k))$ are independent because in each recursive call to RANDOMIZED-SELECT() we invoke RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(), a pivot is randomly selected, and the choice of the pivot in one recursive call is *independent* from the choice of the pivot in another recursive call. Remember that in the analysis we assume that the elements are distinct, so that each element in a particular subarray has the same probability of being selected as the pivot. Moreover, simply stated, the value of $\max(k-1,n-k)$ does not depend on $X_k$: it is the same independently of $X_k$ being equal to zero or one.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why "the choice of the pivot in one recursive call is independent from the choice of the pivot in another recursive call" $\implies$ $Pr\{X_k=a \land \max(k-1,n-k)=m\}=Pr\{X_k=a\}.Pr\{\max(k-1,n-k)=m\}$

Comment: There is a precise assumption: the random numbers are independent, i.e., they must be chosen independently from each other. As a consequence, each time RANDOMIZED-PARTITION() is called,  it generates a completely independent random number from all the other successive times RANDOMIZED-PARTITION() is called. In practice that means that the pivot selected during the $i$-th invocation does not depend functionally on the pivots selected in the previous calls. Finally,  the value of $\max(−1,−)$ does not depend on $X_K$: it is the same independently of $X_K$ being equal to zero or one.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems that "$X_k$ and $T(\max(k-1,n-k)$ are independent" is counter-intuitive, as at glimpse it seems that the value of $X_k$ depends on $k$ and so does $T(\max(k-1,n-k)$. So to clarify the situation we much look at the case and definition more closely.

Now as per the definition, $X_k$ is used to reflect the randomness of the algorithm in the recurrence relation of its time complexity. **A deeper look at the definition of $X_k$ says that it depends on the value of the index of the pivot which is chosen in a particular call to the RANDOMIZED-PARTITION.** As only one index of the array is selected as the pivot in a particular call to RANDOMIZED-PARTITION $X_k$ can have the value $1$ only for that particular pivot index $k$ and all other indices we have $X_k=0$ and the summation on the RHS of the recurrence reduces to only one term.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k.T(\max(k-1,n-k))$$

$$=X_1.T(\max(1-1,n-1))+X_2.T(\max(2-1,n-2))+X_3.T(\max(3-1,n-3))+\ldots+X_n.T(\max(n-1,n-n)) \tag 1$$

Now suppose if RANDOMIZED-PARTITION returns $2$ we have,

$$=0.T(\max(1-1,n-1))+1.T(\max(2-1,n-2))+0.T(\max(3-1,n-3))+\ldots+0.T(\max(n-1,n-n))$$

Or if RANDOMIZED-PARTITION returns $n$ we have,

$$=0.T(\max(1-1,n-1))+0.T(\max(2-1,n-2))+0.T(\max(3-1,n-3))+\ldots+1.T(\max(n-1,n-n))$$

Note that in $(1)$ whatever be the value of $X_k$ the value $T(\max(k-1,n-k))$ does not change, this is so because of the following,

Thought it seems that $X_k$ depends on the summation variable $k$ but it is not the complete truth.

A more closer look into the definition of this indicator random-variable shows that $X_k$ depends on whether a particular value of the summation variable is choosen as the pivot index by the RANDOMIZED-PARTITION. So if in a call RANDOMIZED-PARTITION selects the pivot index as say $j$ then for $k=j$ we have $X_j=1$ and zero for all other $X_{k\neq j}$. So $X_k$ depend on the RANDOMIZED-PARTITION.

On the other hand $T(\max(k-1,n-k))$ is a random variable (as the text defines) but it has as its parameter $\max(k-1,n-k)$ which in turn depends only on the summation variable and no other hidden conditions.

From our above two claims we can say that $X_k$ and $T(\max(k-1,n-k)$ are independent.